# How to stop combo box scroll event from bubbling up the visual tree?

Tags: wpf

I have custom WPF Popup for a combo box that contains a list view to display items. I have a problem when scrolling down on the list view. After the list view scrolls up/down completely the scroll event bubbles up to the parent view and results in the parent view scrolling up/down. What I am expecting is the list view should scroll up/down completely and stop scrolling instead of passing the event up the visual tree.

Comment: You have a custom WPF Popup and you need help with it? Show it.

Comment: No, the pop up shows up fine. After the pop up shows up, I scroll using the mouse wheel over the list that appears in the pop up. Once the list scrolls up/down fully, further scrolls is causing the parent view to scroll up/down. I want this behavior to stop.